# Rest call with jQuery : can't parse data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I wrote a little web service using Slim Framework 3 (in PHP), all returned data are made with this instruction :

```
return $response->withJson($liste);
```

Then I wrote a HTML client using "jquery.rest" plugin, I can see JSON results but can't understand the structure and how to read all these data, please have a look on browser's console :

[image]

I want to write a loop to display the data, but can't figure it out !

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: A working link, some code perhaps, anything helping others to debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an `array of objects` in a response as per the browser console.

You can parse this response in different ways :

## In Javascript

**using for in loop :**

```js
var obj = [
           {"id":"1","task":"Find Bugs","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"},
           {"id":"2","task":"Review","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"}
          ];
    
for (var i in obj) {
  console.log("Task is :"+obj[i].task);
}
```

**using array [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method :**

```js
var obj = [
           {"id":"1","task":"Find Bugs","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"},
     {"id":"2","task":"Review","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"}
    ];
    
var res = obj.map(function(item) {
  return item.task;
});    

console.log(res);
```

## In AngularJS

**using ng-repeat :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [
               {"id":"1","task":"Find Bugs","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"},
               {"id":"2","task":"Review","status":"1","created_at":"2016-04-10 23:50:40"}
              ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in obj">
  {{item.task}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see JSON results but can't understand the structure

You're getting an array of objects.

> how to read all these data

You could use `map` to parse it :

```
result.map(function(obj) { 
     console.log(obj.id,obj.task,obj.status);
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Example :**

```js
var result = [{id: 1, task: "Find", status: 1},{id: 2, task: "Review", status: 2}];

result.map(function(obj) { 
    console.log(obj.id,obj.task,obj.status);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't he just use JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON(provided he is using it of course)??

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @SuperNOVA.. but he want to loop through the data (_I want to write a loop to display the data, but can't figure it out !_).

Comment: Well, you were probably sarcastic but anyway... He could still loop the data  after parsing as JSON and then loop as a normal JS array/object.